# How can I make the shape shadow and reduce distance between rows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

Can anyone help to make the shape shadow and also reduce distance between the first row and second row?

[image]

This is the type of shadow I'm looking for.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
 
\tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20,text width=5em,text badly centered,rounded corners,minimum height=4em]  
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm,auto]  
    
    \node[block]  (n1)  {First};  
    \node[block, right of=n1]  (n2) {Second};  
    \node[block, right of=n2] (n3) {Third};  
    \node[block, below of=n2] (n4) {Forth};  
    \node[block, below of=n3] (n5) {Fifth};  
    
    \begin{scope}[>=stealth,line width=3pt]
    \draw[->, cyan!50] (n1)  -- (n2);  
    \draw[->,cyan!50] (n2) -- (n3);  
    \draw[->,cyan!50] (n2) -- (n4);  
    \draw[->,cyan!50] (n4) -- (n5);  
    \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I defined two types of shadow, `drop shadow` and `shadow`.  You can see the difference on the fifth node.  The arrows have no shadow.  In case you need one... we'll see.

For the distances between nodes, the library `positioning` is invoked.

**Addendum**
Once the nodes have been defined, the arrows among them can be introduced either with an `edge` or with a `to` command.  With the latter, one can have also a syntax like `|-`.

An easy solution to have cast shadows for the arrows is also based on the use of the second form; one can draw each arrow twice.  It is not the prettiest solution though.

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows.blur, arrows.meta, shapes}

\tikzset{
  drop shadow/.style={
    blur shadow={%
      shadow xshift=1.5pt,
      shadow yshift=-1pt,
      shadow blur steps=9,
      shadow blur extra rounding=1.5pt%
    },
  },
  shadow/.style={%
    preaction={%
      fill=black!20, transform canvas={xshift=2.5pt, yshift=-1.5pt}
    }
  },
  block/.style={%
    draw, rectangle, rounded corners,
    orange!50!red!80!black, fill=orange!50!red!90!black,
    text width=5em, text badly centered, text=white,
    minimum height=4em
  },
  spear/.style={%
    arrows={-Latex[length=1em, width=3ex]}, blue!50!cyan!70!black,
    line width=1ex, shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2cm, auto]  
  \node[block, drop shadow]  (n1)  {First};  
  \node[block, drop shadow, right=of n1]  (n2) {Second};  
  \node[block, drop shadow, right=of n2] (n3) {Third};  
  \node[block, drop shadow, below=of n2] (n4) {Forth};  
  \node[block, shadow, below=of n3] (n5) {Fifth};  

  \path[->] (n1) edge[spear] (n2)
  (n2) edge[spear] (n3)
  (n2) edge[spear] (n4)
  (n3) edge[spear] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the addendum, the style `spearCS` was created,

```
  spearCS/.style={%
    arrows={-Latex[length=1em, width=3ex]}, black!20,
    line width=1ex, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt,
    transform canvas={xshift=2pt, yshift=-1.5pt}
```

and then

```
  \draw[spearCS] (n1) to (n2);
  \draw[spearCS] (n2) to (n3);
  \draw[spearCS, rounded corners] (n2) |- (n5);
```

was used.

Comment: Very nice shadow, the arrow shadow is not needed but I'm curious if it looks better with shadow. I like the fifth best.

Comment: Would it be able to make the arrow work when it's a combination of two straight lines such as `(node1) |- (node2)`?

Comment: Hi!  I added some code to go along your questions/remarks.

Comment: And if you like the solution, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use shorten >=3pt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{4}
 
\tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20,text width=5em,text badly centered,rounded corners,minimum height=4em]  
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt]  
    
    \node[block]  (n1)  {First};  
    \node[block, right of=n1]  (n2) {Second};  
    \node[block, right of=n2] (n3) {Third};  
    \node[block, below of=n2] (n4) {Forth};  
    \node[block, below of=n3] (n5) {Fifth};  
    
    \begin{scope}[>=stealth,line width=3pt]
    \draw[->, cyan!50] (n1)  -- (n2);  
    \draw[->,cyan!50] (n2) -- (n3);  
    \draw[->,cyan!50] (n2) -- (n4);  
    \draw[->,cyan!50] (n4) -- (n5);  
    \end{scope}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you add shadow for the shape?

Answer (score 1):

I use the library `arrows.meta` and `positioning`.
I failed to set the line thickness and the arrow at the same time. I created a command that draws the line and then the arrow.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzset{every node/.style={
            draw=black,
            fill=blue!20,
            text width=5em,
            text centered,
            rounded corners,
            minimum height=4em,
            node distance=1cm and 2cm, auto
            },
        trait/.style={
            line width=7pt,
            cyan!50,        
            shorten >=7pt
            },
        arrow/.style={
            -Triangle,
            line width=3pt,
            cyan!50
        }
        }
\newcommand{\joint}[2]{%
            \draw[trait] (#1)  -- (#2); 
            \draw[arrow] (#1)  -- (#2);
            }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  (n1)  {First};  
    \node[right= of n1] (n2) {Second};  
    \node[right= of n2] (n3) {Third};
    \node[below= of n2] (n4) {Forth};  
    \node[below= of n3] (n5) {Fifth};  
    

    \joint{n1}{n2}
    \joint{n2}{n3}
    \joint{n2}{n4}
    \joint{n4}{n5}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT2**
With the code of Daniel N. I learned to do both at the same time, the code is simplified

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzset{every node/.style={
            draw=black,
            fill=blue!20,
            text width=5em,
            text centered,
            rounded corners,
            minimum height=4em,
            node distance=1cm and 2cm, auto
            },
        trait/.style={
            arrows={-Triangle[length=1em, width=3ex]},
            line width=7pt,
            cyan!50,        
            %shorten >=7pt
            }
        % arrow/.style={
        %     arrows={-Triangle[length=1em, width=3ex]},
        %     %-Triangle,
        %     line width=3pt,
        %     cyan!50
        % }
        }
% \newcommand{\joint}[2]{%
%             \draw[trait] (#1)  -- (#2); 
%             \draw[arrow] (#1)  -- (#2);
%             }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  (n1)  {First};  
    \node[right= of n1] (n2) {Second};  
    \node[right= of n2] (n3) {Third};
    \node[below= of n2] (n4) {Forth};  
    \node[below= of n3] (n5) {Fifth};  
    

    \draw[trait] (n1)--(n2);
    \draw[trait] (n2)--(n3);
    \draw[trait] (n2)--(n4);
    \draw[trait] (n4)--(n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By use of `arrows.meta`, `positioning` and `shadows` library, and simple default `drop shadows` option at defining nodes' shape. For nodes positioning is used `positioning˛library syntax (see comments in code):

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shadows}        % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 11mm,   % set desired distance between nodes <vertical> and <horizontal>       
   box/.style = {draw, fill=red, rounded corners,
                 minimum height=4em, text width=5em, align=flush center,
                 text=white,
                 drop shadow},
every edge/.append style = {draw=cyan, line width=3mm, -{Triangle[length=3mm,width=5mm]},
                            shorten <=1mm, shorten >=0.5mm}
                        ]
%
\node[box]  (n1)  {First};
\node[box, right=of n1] (n2) {Second};  % observe "=of <node name>" instead yourd "of = <node name>"
\node[box, right=of n2] (n3) {Third};
\node[box, below=of n2] (n4) {Forth};
\node[box, below=of n3] (n5) {Fifth};
%
\draw   (n1) edge (n2)
        (n2) edge (n3)
        (n2) edge (n4)
        (n4) edge (n5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
However, if you prefer to have blurred shadows, than you need instead of `shadows` to load `blur.shadows` library (it support `shadow` library too) abd in above code replace nodes option `drop shadow` with `blur shadow`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shadows.blur}        % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 11mm,   % set desired distance between nodes yvertical> and <horizontal>
   box/.style = {draw, fill=red, rounded corners,
                 minimum height=4em, text width=5em, align=flush center,
                 text=white,
                 drop shadow},
every edge/.append style = {draw=cyan, line width=3mm, -{Triangle[length=3mm,width=5mm]},
                            shorten <=1mm, shorten >=0.5mm}
                        ]
% rest is the same as in above MWE
```

Compilation result:

[image]

Note: So far `blur.shadows` is not described in the `tikz` bundle documentation. For details of it see [pgf-blur – PGF/TikZ package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-blur?lang=en).